# Code Formatting: Add space around binary operators in JSX code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, eslint, prettier

I noticed that any JavaScript inside my file was getting correctly formatted (spaces being inserted correctly between operators by Prettier) but for `JSX` code the spaces do not get inserted correctly.

Example-
[image]

This is my `.eslintrc.json` file-

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": ["react-app", "prettier"],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 12
    },
    "plugins": ["react", "prettier"],
    "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": [
            "error",
            {
                "singleQuote": true,
                "trailingComma": "es5",
                "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
                "useTabs": true,
                "endOfLine": "auto",
                "jsxSingleQuote": true
            }
        ],
        "arrow-body-style": "off",
        "prefer-arrow-callback": "off",
        "quotes": ["error", "single"],
        "space-infix-ops": ["warn", { "int32Hint": false }],
        "space-unary-ops": [
            "warn",
            {
                "words": true,
                "nonwords": false,
                "overrides": {
                    "++": true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there any property I can add for Prettier or Eslint that allows me to add spaces between operators in JSX. Or an extension or any other way to solve formatting inconsistencies like these ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to use Prettier, this appears to be impossible. However, if you're fine with giving Prettier up, [`eslint-plugin-react`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react) provides an ESLint rule which allows you to require spaces around the equals sign: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-equals-spacing.md.

```json
"react/jsx-equals-spacing": ["error", "always"]
```

Comment: To add to my answer though, I don't think I have ever seen spaces around the equals sign in that context be preferred for JSX or HTML. If you're planning on having other people work on this project, I would reconsider whether that's a style rule that you actually want.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for so thank you! But this property seems to be conflicting with prettier (I checked using `eslint-config-prettier` command). Now I can't figure out which property it is conflicting with. But are you certain that having spaces around operators etc in JSX isn't the best practice ?

Comment: @Pranav_m7 there's no such thing as "best practice" when it comes to code style, only a matter of conformity. And I agree with Unlocked, I've never seen a code style that prefers spaces around `=` in JSX or HTML attributes, it's not precedented.

Comment: Like Patrick says, ultimately it comes down to style, but I've never seen people use spaces there before. After actually creating a project and testing this myself, I believe that prettier has a [non-configurable](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html) rule that forces no space around the equals sign in JSX, so your only real option if you really wanted that rule would be to ditch prettier. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @Pranav_m7 have you ever seen a project with such spaces?

Comment: I am not sure about JSX, recently started working in it but in one other project(Python based ) that I was doing with someone else, they were strictly using Pep8 rules to format the code that had spaces between all operators. I get it now, HTML and JSX need not have spaces between operators.

Comment: For beginners, it's always a good idea to stick to default/recommended settings of tools like Prettier. They're recommended for a reason. Just use the defaults, and don't get distracted by configuring those tools.